# 403 Forbidden on form submission

Tags: php, http-status-code-403

I have a url that returns 403 forbidden for some unknown reason. i have disable mod_security in .htaccess, chmodded file to 0777. The URL is

http://www.veepiz.com/afrostar.php?app=help&func=addvideo

it happens when u submit the form any ideas?

here is the code

```
function PublicAddVideo()
    {
    if (isset($_POST['submit_addvideo']))
        {
        require_once("class.phpmailer.php");     
        //send email tobirthday person
        $subject="New AfroStar Video Suggested";
        $msg = "Dear Jordah,\n".
              "Youtube video: ".$_POST['youtubesle']."\n Star Name: ".$_POST['starnamesle']."\n Country: ".$_POST['countrysle']."\n IP Address: ".getRealIpAddr();
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();                                      // set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = "localhost";  // specify main and backup server
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = "support@veepiz.com";  // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = "********"; // SMTP password
        $mail->From = "support@veepiz.com";
        $mail->FromName = "Veepiz";
        $mail->AddAddress('jordahz@hotmail.com',"Jordah Ferguson");
        $mail->AddReplyTo("support@veepiz.com", "Veepiz");
        $mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // set word wrap to 50 characters
        $mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body    = nl2br($msg);
        $mail->AltBody = $msg;
        if(!$mail->Send())
            {
            }
        ?>
        <div style='color:green;'>Admins at veepiz.com have been notified of your request and will update afrostar application accordingly.<div align='center' style='padding:10px'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a  href='afrostar.php' onclick="return getPage('afrostar_class.php',{});" class='btn'>Back to AfroStars</a></div></div>
        <?php             
        } else
        {
        $this->DisplayHeader("Add African Video");    
        ?>
        <script language="javascript">
          var checkHelpVars=function ()
            {
            err='';
            if ($('#starnamesle').val().length==0) err+="Please type in the name of the star";
            if ($('#countrysle').val().length==0) err+="\nName of the country missing";
            if ($('#youtubesle').val().length==0) err+="\nYoutube url missing";
            var url=$('#youtubesle').val();
            var matches = url.match(/^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube.com\/watch\?(?=.*v=[\w-]+)(?:\S+)?$/);
            if (matches) {
                } else {
                err +="\nInvalid Youtube Url";
                }                
            if (err.length>0)
                {
                alert(err);
                return false;    
                }    
            <?php 
            if (isloggedin())
                {
                echo "return postPage('afrostar_class.php?app=help&func=addvideo',{starnamesle:$('#starnamesle').val(),countrysle:$('#countrysle').val(),youtubesle:encodeURI($('#youtubesle').val()),submit_addvideo:1});";    
                } else
                {
                echo "return true;";    
                }                     
            ?>
            }  
        </script>
        <form id='helpform' method="POST" action="http://www.veepiz.com/afrostar.php?app=help&amp;func=addvideo">
        <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="3">
            <tr>
                <td><b>Africa Artist Name:</b></td>
                <td><input id='starnamesle' type="text" style='' name='starnamesle' style='-webkit-border-radius: 8px;-moz-border-radius: 8px;border-radius: 8px;width:450px'/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Country:</b></td>
                <td><input id='countrysle' type="text" style='' name='countrysle' style='-webkit-border-radius: 8px;-moz-border-radius: 8px;border-radius: 8px;width:450'/></td>
            </tr>                
            <tr>
                <td><b>Youtube link:</b></td>
                <td><input id='youtubesle' type="text" style='' name='countrysle' style='-webkit-border-radius: 8px;-moz-border-radius: 8px;border-radius: 8px;width:450'/><br/>Example:<small style='font-size:8pt;color:#666666'>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vJyftjMOd2w</small></td>
            </tr>                
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" class="btn" onclick="return checkHelpVars();" name='submit_addvideo' value="Finish"></td>
            </tr>                
        </table>
        </form>

        <?php    
        $this->DisplayFooter();
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

Check your post data, if it contains any url then there are chances to get blocked in server.

you should replace certain characters in the url you are submitting then you need convert back to its  original form on post.

Comment: Thanks.. Really helpful :)

Comment: How do i do this? Assuming i have a textbox in a form, how do i replace the textbox data and at which point do i convert it back before saving to a database?

Answer (score 1):

**My solution:**

> it sounds like you are not urlencoding the URL you're passing before
>   you embed it in the URL of the script you're passing to.

Answer (score 0):

i realised i had name defined twice for countrysle.... so i changed it to this and now it works[within form]

```
        <tr>
            <td><b>Country:</b></td>
            <td><input id='countrysle' type="text"  name='countrysle' style='-webkit-border-radius: 8px;-moz-border-radius: 8px;border-radius: 8px;width:250px'/></td>
        </tr>                
        <tr>
            <td><b>Youtube link:</b></td>
            <td><input id='youtubesle' type="text" name='youtubesle' style='-webkit-border-radius: 8px;-moz-border-radius: 8px;border-radius: 8px;width:250px'/><br/>Example:<small style='font-size:8pt;color:#666666'>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vJyftjMOd2w</small></td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the `type= "text"` attribute in your input tag of the field you are having the problem with. Also try and use `method= "post"` in the form attributes rather than get which can also cause this problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a **.htaccess** file
2. Put this line **SecFilterEngine Off** into .htaccess file
3. Keep this htaccess file in **root** folder

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else struggling with this, it's definitely worth checking the `$_POST` global as other people have recommended.

In my case, in my ignorance, my issue was that I was making a `fetch()` request from my JS. I `print_r`'d my globals and there was nothing in them. I found it rather strange given that the payload in the outgoing request had all of the data that I needed and had also specified that it was a `POST` request.

I have used AJAX in the past but did not want to use jQuery in this instance as it would simply be for this one request.

For anyone in my situation and wanting to use `fetch()` to do a `POST` request to a PHP script, it is vital to use the [FormData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) interface.

Answer (score -2):

Incredibly, I found that if I changed the post string from 'blank form webpage' to 'blank webpage', i.e. omitting the technical word 'form', the form would post the text without the server throwing up a 'Forbidden' message!!!