# Why can't I submit text that contains the function fgets()?

Tags: php, html, fgets

I use my website to code (and progress in my programming projects) online, during school, and send the code to my email address to continue working on it at home.

The text can be inside a `<textarea>` or an `<input>` field (with `name="Code" id="Code"`).
Either way, I'm unable to submit text that contains the C/C++ function **`fgets()`**:

```
TODO: Include a more stable function to get user input,
      such as fgets(input, 20, stdin);
```

I have no idea why submitting the text: `fgets(input, 20, stdin)` would be a problem, and why *any* text inside a `<textarea>` or `<input>` would be a problem since it's all just plain text, and not actual code.

When I click submit, while text in my `<textarea>` contains `fgets()`, nothing happens (instead of giving me `Invalid input` message or `Email Sent` message), and my text isn't being sent.

Comment: *What* happens? Does your browser window close, do you get an error message. Please be specific about "unable to submit".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forbidden Error When Submitting Simple PHP Form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824511/forbidden-error-when-submitting-simple-php-form)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be that something on your server sees this as an attempt to hack the site.

A quick Googling shows that `mod_security` (a fairly common Apache module that attempts to prevent things like SQL injection and other exploits) may be blocking `POST` parameters that include `fgets()` calls. http://forums.modx.com/thread?thread=9677

Comment: Is there anything I can do to make it possible to send text that contains PHP functions?

Comment: Sure, disable mod_security (or ask your web host to do so).

Comment: Okay, I think I'll keep it enabled (for security) and go through the text in JavaScript to modify PHP functions in it, such as: `fgets(input, 20, stdin); ==> fg-ets(input, 20, stdin);`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't transform arguments to one string on your own (or if so, use some [javascript alternative to phps `urlencode()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp)).

jQuery supports [[1]](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), [[2]](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) `data` as [anonymous object](http://3dmdesign.com/development/javascript-variables-and-anonymous-objects)

> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if
>   not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See
>   processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must
>   be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple
>   values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting
>   (described below).

so you can use:

```
data: {
  'Name': name,
  'Code': code,
  ...
}
```

and it should work and what's more important it takes care about correct encoding (escaping). If this doesn't help (the problem isn't with malformed "*raw data*") try  [ceejayoz's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12876762/1149736).