# Notice:Undefined index:user & pass

Tags: php, forms, cookies

This is a script using cookies for password.....running it on localhost it show the notice
   undefined index:user
   undefined index:pass
The code is as follows:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo ($self); ?>" method="post">
Please enter your details for access :<br>
Name:<input type="text" name="user" size="10">
Password:<input type="text" name="pass" size="10"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Log in">
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
$user=$_POST['user'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];
$self=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if(($user!=null)and ($pass!=null))
{
 if($pass=="mypassword")
  {
    setcookie("checkpass","okkay");
header("Location:loggedin.php");
exit();
  }
 else
  {
  setcookie("checkpass");
 } 
}
?>
```

Comment: dont store passwords or usernames in cookies, that is really really really bad..

Comment: he doesn't store the password in the cookie, instead he sets a cookie to check if the password was valid, is still bad but not as bad as storing the password

Comment: Sidenote: You're outputting before header with the cookie.

Comment: use `$user = (isset($_POST['user'])?($_POST['user']):(die ("missing POST argument user"));` and same with password... you're not getting anything from $_POST if it says that the index is undefined.

Comment: On replacing with the above code  it displays-Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'

Comment: @Fred-ii-i tried putting php before html ....still doesn't work

Comment: Consult my answer below @arpit You needed a conditional statement `isset` to check if your variables are set or not. Plus, read the added note about password storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you need to use `isset` and wrapping that conditional statement around your PHP.

Plus, you will get an error message such as:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at.....

So, place your PHP above HTML.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])){

$user=$_POST['user'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];
$self=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if(($user!=null) and ($pass!=null))
{
 if($pass=="mypassword")
  {
    setcookie("checkpass","okkay");

// echo "OK";

 header("Location:loggedin.php");
exit();
  }
 else
  {
  setcookie("checkpass");

// echo "SORRY";

 } 
}

} // brace for if(isset($_POST['user']) ...
?>

<html>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo ($self); ?>" method="post">
Please enter your details for access :<br>
Name:<input type="text" name="user" size="10">
Password:<input type="text" name="pass" size="10"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Log in">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Passwords**

I also noticed that you may be storing passwords in plain text. This is not recommended.

Use one of the following:

- [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471)
- [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
- [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)
- [`scrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)
- [**On OPENWALL**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)
- [**PBKDF2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
- [**PBKDF2 on PHP.net**](http://php.net/hash-pbkdf2)
- PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.
- Compatibility pack (if PHP < 5.5) https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/

Other links:

- [**PBKDF2 For PHP**](https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm)

Comment: this works errors are removed....but on clicking submit button it shows access forbidden! Error 403

Comment: That's most likely to be a webserver/configuration issue. I know next to nothing about localhost stuff, unfortunately. @arpit

Comment: [**See this page**](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1905/Why+am+I+seeing+a+403+Forbidden+error+message%3F) which may help. @arpit

Comment: Consult [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8826115/) on SO also. @arpit

Comment: kk....no problem..the code i posted is wrking well...only showing those two notice....still thnx for your efforts...i am just new to php

Comment: You're quite welcome @arpit